# Topological degree of differentiable map using line integrals?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, curves-and-surfaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ be a $C^1$ function that vanishes at a point $x_0.$

I can then define $$-i \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \nabla \log(f(s)) \cdot ds := - i \int_0^1 \nabla (\log f)(\gamma_\varepsilon(t)) \cdot \gamma_\varepsilon'(t) \ dt,$$ where $$\gamma_\varepsilon(t) = x_0 + \varepsilon (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$$

for $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small, such that we enclose only one root of $f$.

I am trying to understand if this defines a reasonable winding number in the sense that it is discrete-valued $\in 2\pi \mathbb Z$. I don't quite see why this is the case. Is this perhaps a well-known construction?

Comment: it's independent of $\epsilon$, the integral is $2\pi$ times the multiplicity of the root.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker does this winding number have a name or do you have a reference where these properties are discussed?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: @CarloBeenakker but here we are not considering holomorphic functions but just real differentiable functions?

Comment: You need isolated roots, differentiable  is not enough. For example, this example you mentioned earlier of $f(x)=x_1$ fails, it vanishes on the entire imaginary axis.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I see, but then $f(x,y)=x+iy$ and $f(x,y)=x+iy^2$ give the same value? I am still not quite sure I see what computation implies this invariance...

Comment: these two function give different values, one has winding number 1, the other winding number 0; I have worked this out in the answer box.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you for your answer, but then the integral is not $2\pi$ times the multiplicity of the root?

Comment: I should not have used the word multiplicity, it refers to real functions; in the complex plane winding number is the correct word; a function $f(z)=z^p$ has winding number $p$ in the complex plane, and multiplicity $p$ of its root on the real axis, but for your function $x+iy^2$ only winding number makes sense (you could argue it has  multiplicity 1 along the real axis and 2 along the imaginary axis, so that is not a unique definition)

Comment: thank you very much, that makes sense...

Comment: @AntónioBorgesSantos: have you looked into [topological degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) of differentiable maps?

Comment: @M.G. that's interesting, do you think you can make the connection explicit?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I just opened a bounty, since I think I still don't quite know why this expression is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Integer-valuedness of the winding number:**

I assume that the function $f$ has an *isolated* root at the origin and I integrate along a circle centered at the origin, $x+iy=\varepsilon\cos 2\pi t+i\varepsilon\sin 2\pi t$. The radius $\varepsilon$ is small enough that no other root is inside the circle, and moreover $f(t)$ does not vanish on the circle.

I decompose $f(t)$ on the circle into modulus and phase,
$$f(t)=|f(t)|e^{i\phi_0}e^{i\phi(t)},\;\;|f(t)|>0,\;\;f(0)=f(1).$$
I define $z(t)\equiv-i\ln e^{i\phi(t)}\in(-\pi,\pi]$. The logarithm has a branch cut on the imaginary real axis. The $t$-independent offset $\phi_0$ is chosen such that $z(0)=0=z(1)$, in order to avoid the branch cut at the initial and final times.

We wish to show that the integral
$$I=-i\int_0^1 \frac{d\ln f(t)}{dt}\,dt=-i\int_0^1 \frac{d\ln |f(t)|}{dt}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{dz(t)}{dt}\,dt$$
is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

The modulus $|f(t)|$ does not cross the branch cut of the logarithm, hence
$$\int_0^1 \frac{d\ln |f(t)|}{dt}\,dt=\ln|f(1)|-\ln|f(0)|=0.$$
The function $z(t)$ is a piecewise continuous function, consisting of $N$ continuous segments $z_1(t),z_2(t),\ldots z_N(t)$, connected by $\pm 2\pi$ jumps at each $t=t_1,t_2,\ldots t_{N-1}$ where the branch cut of the logarithm is crossed:
$$z_p(t_{p})-z_{p+1}(t_p)=\sigma_p 2\pi,\;\;p=1,\ldots N-1,\;\;\sigma_p\in\{+1,-1\}.$$
We define $t_0=0$, $t_N=1$, hence $z(t_0)=0=z(t_N)$. The integral then evaluates to
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dz(t)}{dt}\,dt=\sum_{p=1}^N \int_{t_{p-1}}^{t_p}\frac{dz_p(t)}{dt}\,dt=\sum_{p=1}^N \bigl(z_p(t_p)-z_p(t_{p-1})\bigr)=\sum_{p=1}^{N-1}\sigma_p 2\pi.$$
The net sum of the $\pm 2\pi$ jumps is the winding number $W=\sum_{p=1}^{N-1}\sigma_p$, which indeed is an integer.

**Comment:** I did not use analyticity of $f$ in the complex plane, the winding number $W$ is an integer for any continuous function which does not vanish on the integration contour. The connection with the multiplicity of the root inside the contour requires analyticity, so that near a root $f\propto(x+iy)^W$.

**Example:**
In these plots I compare $z(t)$ for the two functions mentioned by the OP, $f_1=x+iy$ (left plot) and $f_2=x+iy^2$ (right plot). Both have an isolated root at the origin, but only $f_1$ is analytic. The first function has one $2\pi$ jump in $z(t)$, winding number 1, while the second function has no jump at all, winding number 0.

[image]